# XML Tag Value Extract from Clob column with Multiple Tags with Same Name in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

This is my clob data

```
<id>ID001</id>
<atrbtList>
    <Atrbts>
        <atrTyp>1</atrTyp>
        <atrVal>04120101254</atrVal>
    </Atrbts>
    <Atrbts>
        <atrTyp>2</atrTyp>
        <atrVal>1254</atrVal>
    </Atrbts>
</atrbtList>
```

in a table.

I need to extract data in the form of

```
ID    |Type |Value 
------------------
ID001 | 1   |04120101254
ID001 | 2   |1254
```

Currently i'm using the oracle xml extract function and this is as far as i've gone with the query

```
    SELECT 
        XMLTYPE(xml_clob).extract('//id/text()').getStringVal() AS Id,
        EXTRACTVALUE( s1.COLUMN_VALUE, '//atrTyp' ) AS AtrTyp,
        EXTRACTVALUE( s.COLUMN_VALUE, '//atrVal' ) AS AtrVal
    FROM   table_name T,
           TABLE(
             XMLSequence(
               EXTRACT(
                 XMLType( T.xml_clob ),
                 '//atrVal'
               )
             )
           ) s,
           TABLE(
             XMLSequence(
               EXTRACT(
                 XMLType( T.xml_clob ),
                 '//atrTyp'
               )
             )
           ) s1
```

and this yields the result set

```
ID    |Type |Value 
------------------
ID001   1   04120101254
ID001   2   04120101254
ID001   1   1254
ID001   2   1254
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction to get the desired result and I also feel the the query could be improved or there is better way to do it which i'm missing.

PS :
Table and it's contents

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (xml_clob CLOB );

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 
'<data><id>ID001</id><atrbtList><Atrbts><atrTyp>1</atrTyp><atrVal>04120101254</atrVal></Atrbts><Atrbts><atrTyp>2</atrTyp><atrVal>1254</atrVal></Atrbts></atrbtList></data>'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing cross join 2x2 = 4. You should get atrbtList as table (sequence of Atrbts):

```
 SELECT XMLTYPE(xml_clob).extract('//id/text()').getStringVal() AS Id,
        EXTRACTVALUE( s.COLUMN_VALUE, '/Atrbts/atrTyp' ) AS AtrTyp,
        EXTRACTVALUE( s.COLUMN_VALUE, '/Atrbts/atrVal' ) AS AtrVal
    FROM   table_name T,
           TABLE(
             XMLSequence(
               EXTRACT(
                 XMLType( T.xml_clob ),
                 '/data/atrbtList/*'
               )
             )
           ) s
```